# How do I use GHC.Exts.breakpoint?

Tags: debugging, haskell, ghc, ghci

The `GHC.Exts` package exports [`breakpoint` and `breakpointCond`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/GHC-Exts.html#g:6). Does anyone know how to use these functions?

From their names I guess they would allow me to set up permanent GHCi breakpoints, but when I add them to my program nothing happens. For example, no breakpoints are triggered when I load this program into GHCi and run it with `main`, `:main`, or `:trace main`:

```
import GHC.Exts

idNat x = breakpointCond (x > 0) x

main = do
  putStrLn "Starting main"
  putStrLn . show $ idNat 3
  putStrLn $ breakpoint "Ending main"
```

Note: I know how to set breakpoints in GHCi using `:break` and I'm using GHC 7.6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the commit history, it seems like this feature [used to work at some point](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/changeset/31751ccacc24ebe5d15a0af84b10dc612d455440/ghc). However, apparently it got removed (either accidentally or on purpose) [when the implementation of breakpoints was reworked](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/commit/cdce647711c0f46f5799b24de087622cb77e647f) (grep for `breakpointName`). I've [filed a ticket about this](http://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/8429).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a summary of some workarounds, none very satisfactory.

### An obvious workaround that doesn't actually work

1. Put this `Breakpoint` module in your source tree:

   ```
   module Breakpoint where

   breakpoint :: a -> a
   breakpoint x = x

   breakpointCond :: Bool -> a -> a
   breakpointCond True  x = x
   breakpointCond False x = x
   ```
2. Import `Breakpoint` instead of `GHC.Exts`.  (We can only set breakpoints on interpreted code, so we can't simply set break points on the `GHC.Exts` break point functions.)
3. Load your code in GHCi and set appropriate break points in the `Breakpoint` module:

   ```
   ghci> :load <your main module>
   ghci> :break Breakpoint 4
   ghci> :break Breakpoint 7
   ```

   Note that the second break point is on the `True` branch of `breakpointCond`.
4. Trace your code:

   ```
   ghci> :trace main
   ```

### Problems with obvious approach

The problem with this approach is that you get a bunch of break points
in the `Breakpoint` module, but when you reach them your actual
computation (what you really care about) is usually not in the history
trace.  I don't understand why this is, but here's an example to
illustrate it:

```
module Eg2 where
import Breakpoint

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = breakpoint $ fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Then:

```
ghci> :load Eg2.hs
ghci> :break Breakpoint 4
```

Now, note that `fib 3 = fib 2 + fib 1 = (fib 1 + fib 0) + fib 1`, so that we `fib 3` should result in us hitting two break points, once at `fib 3` and once at `fib 2`.  However:

```
ghci> :trace fib 3
Stopped at Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20
_result :: a = _
[Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20] *Eg2
ghci> :history 
-1  : fib (Eg2.hs:6:13-46)
-2  : fib (Eg2.hs:(4,5)-(6,46))
<end of history>
[Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20] *Eg2
ghci> :back 
Logged breakpoint at Eg2.hs:6:13-46
_result :: a1
n :: Integer
[-1: Eg2.hs:6:13-46] *Eg2
ghci> n
3
```

So, yes, we hit a break point at `fib 3`. But then:

```
[-1: Eg2.hs:6:13-46] *Eg2
ghci> :continue 
Stopped at Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20
_result :: a = _
[Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20] *Eg2
ghci> :history 
-1  : breakpoint (Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20)
-2  : fib (Eg2.hs:6:13-46)
-3  : fib (Eg2.hs:(4,5)-(6,46))
<end of history>
[Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20] *Eg2
ghci> :back 
Logged breakpoint at Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20
_result :: a
[-1: Breakpoint.hs:4:5-20] *Eg2
ghci> :back 
Logged breakpoint at Eg2.hs:6:13-46
_result :: a1
n :: Integer
[-2: Eg2.hs:6:13-46] *Eg2
ghci> n
3
```

Only the `fib 3` is on the stack?  There is no `fib 2` call, even
though we're currently stopped at its breakpoint!  Indeed, continuing
finishes, returning `fib 3 = 2`:

```
[-2: Eg2.hs:6:13-46] *Eg2
ghci> :continue 
2
```

### Improvement

It's not hard to make the context of the `breakpoint` call available
at the break point. Although this doesn't solve the issue of the
history trace not telling you how you got to the break point, it does
let you inspect the context interactively (so better than "printf
debugging" with `Debug.Trace`).

Add a context argument to the break point functions:

```
module Breakpoint2 where

breakpoint :: b -> a -> a
breakpoint y x =
  const x y

breakpointCond :: Bool -> b -> a -> a
breakpointCond True  y x =
  const x y
breakpointCond False _ x = x
```

Because GHCi only shows the free variables when you stop at a break
point, you can't go with a simpler definition like

```
breakpoint y x = x
```

Now consider our example again, but this time where we manually pass
the context we care about to `breakpoint`:

```
module Eg3 where
import Breakpoint2

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = breakpoint ("n",n) $ fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

No we can inspect `n`:

```
ghci> :load Eg3.hs 
ghci> :break Breakpoint2 5
```

See `n = 3` on the first call:

```
ghci> :trace fib 3
Stopped at Breakpoint2.hs:5:7-15
_result :: a = _
x :: a = _
y :: ([Char], Integer) = ("n",3)
[Breakpoint2.hs:5:7-15] *Eg3
ghci> :continue
```

See `n = 2` on the second call:

```
Stopped at Breakpoint2.hs:5:7-15
_result :: a = _
x :: a = _
y :: ([Char], Integer) = ("n",2)
```

Interactively compute using the context:

```
[Breakpoint2.hs:5:7-15] *Eg3
ghci> let (_,n) = y
[Breakpoint2.hs:5:7-15] *Eg3
ghci> n * n
4
```

However, the trace history is still fairly useless, including the
`breakpoint` calls, but `fib` calls in which they occur.

### Comparison with setting a break point on directly on your code

The goal of the `breakpoint` function is to allow you easily set
persistent break points in your code, versus using a bunch of `:break <some line> <your module>`
statements which become invalid each time your line numbers change.  However, manually
setting breakpoints does yield much better history traces.  For example:

```
module Eg4 where

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Set breakpoint directly:

```
ghci> :load Eg4.hs 
ghci> :break Eg4 5 13
```

We need to column number (13) to make the breakpoint on the RHS of
`fib`, instead of on the whole definition.  Now we get proper traces:

```
ghci> :trace fib 4
Stopped at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1 = _
n :: Integer = 4
[Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :continue 
Stopped at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1 = _
n :: Integer = 3
[Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :continue 
Stopped at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1 = _
n :: Integer = 2
[Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :continue 
Stopped at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1 = _
n :: Integer = 2
[Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :back
Logged breakpoint at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1
n :: Integer
[-1: Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> n
2
[-1: Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :back 
Logged breakpoint at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1
n :: Integer
[-2: Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> n
3
[-2: Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :back 
Logged breakpoint at Eg4.hs:5:13-33
_result :: a1
n :: Integer
[-3: Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> n
4
[-3: Eg4.hs:5:13-33] *Eg4
ghci> :history 
-1  : fib (Eg4.hs:5:13-33)
-2  : fib (Eg4.hs:5:13-33)
-3  : fib (Eg4.hs:5:13-33)
-4  : fib (Eg4.hs:(3,5)-(5,33))
<end of history>
```

### Final note on `breakpointCond`

The `breakpointCond` seems even more useful, since GHCi doesn't have
conditional breakpoints, but these can be affected by editing your
code to include pointless branching on break point conditions.  For
example, suppose we only want to break when `n` is even:

```
module Eg5 where

fib 0 = 0
fib 1 = 1
fib n = case even n of
          True  -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
          False -> fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

Now, breaking on line 6, we only stop on even `n`.  Of course, this
transformation is a little annoying, e.g. we can't instead do

```
fib n = case even n of
          True  -> r
          False -> r
  where r = fib (n-1) + fib (n-2)
```

since then `n` is not free in `r`, and we can't use an "if" statement,
since GHCi won't let you set a break point inside one.